# Tomcat ServeletException NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: exception, tomcat

I have a webapp I'll call "App1" I am using to create some webplots. I have the .jar files in webapps/App1/lib/ and when I visit the server, I find that I am able to launch some webapps, but others I get funny exceptions. One, being

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChartConstants
```

Then, when I add the jfreechart jar to the classpath, I get a different error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jrefinery/util/ObjectUtils
```

tomcat version: 7.0.19
OS: ubuntu 12.04

I've tried it on a windows installation and it seems to work just fine. So I'm guessing it's a classpath error? I've tried adding the jfreechart-*.jar to the catalina classpath but it doesn't seem to fix anything. I've also tried to copy the webapp/App1/lib/ jar files to the top level/lib folder and this doesn't fix anything either.

Any ideas here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the correct jar file in your project.

The jfreechart project has been repackaged. If you include the old jfreechart-0.9.3.jar, it will fix your compiler errors.

jfreechart-0.9.3.jar
download : http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/jfreechart/jfreechart/0.9.3/jfreechart-0.9.3.jar

Comment: I included that before, I believe. Anyway, it was some sort of port error, I had to change all the ports in the server .xml file to get it to work. Sorry for not responding earlier. Thanks!